# Declarative OSGi Services

Tags: java, service, osgi

I have a question about declarative OSGi Services. I have the following interface :

```
  public interface PrintService {
    public void print();
  }
```

and its implementation:

```
    public class PrintServiceImpl implements PrintService {

      @Override
      public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello from PrintServiceImpl!");
      }
    }
```

OSGI-INF/component.xml :

```
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="service">
   <implementation class="service.PrintServiceImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="print.PrintService"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

MANIFEST.MF :

```
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/component.xml
```

After I install the service and start it nothing happend. How can I activate it and print "*Hello from PrintServiceImpl!*" to console.

Comment: Can you see your declared service in the administration console ? is it active ?

Comment: Yes I do with command "ss" and it's active, but with command "ls" state is "Unsatisfied".

Comment: Check if you have the bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` and its dependencies added to your launch-configuration

Comment: @TomSeidel do you mean launch-configuration in Eclipse? I set bundle org.eclipse.equinox.ds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect your `print` method to be invoked? It is part of the interface of the service, so it will not be invoked until you can a client that binds to it and calls it.

If you type the `services` command in the console you should see that your bundle is publishing the `print.PrintService` service; this means that your component is working. If you don't see this then you may be missing something like the SCR bundle as suggested by Tom Seidel in the comments above.

Comment: how can I invoke print method ?

Comment: Some other code in another bundle will have to get the service and call the method.

Comment: Why did you write a print method if you have no client that wants to call it?

Answer (score 3):

You should make explicit that you want you service to start when the bundle is started. Otherwise, it will be instantiated lazily, and give that no other service requires the PrintService, it will not be instantiated at all.

You can control your service lifecycle (with regard to the bundle lifecycle) using the attributes `enabled` and `immediate`. `enabled` is trivial: indicates whether your service is enabled or not when the bundle is started. `immediate` indicates whether this service is lazy ot not. `immediate="true"` will start your service *immediatly*, `immediate="false"` will apply lazy instantiation (i.e. wait until some other service requests this service as a dependency)

e.g.

```
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="PrintService"
activate="activate" 
deactivate="deactivate"
modified="modified"
enabled="true" 
immediate="true">
```

As Chris mentioned, if you want your service to do something when it's activated, you should add some code to the `activate` lifecycle method (note that the name of the method can be specified in the component descriptor like it was done explicitly above)

```
protected final void activate() {
    print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to do the print from your activate method?

```
public class PrintServiceImpl implements PrintService {
    protected final void activate() {
        System.out.println("Hello from PrintServiceImpl!");
    }
    protected final void deactivate() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye from PrintServiceImpl!");
    }
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, Neil's answer is the right one: you want a client that uses the service via ServiceTracker or `<reference>` and explicitly invokes the print() method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've found that in activator xml file can pass activate method :)

Comment: This is true, that you can specify an arbitrary method as the activate method. For maintainability of the code, I recommend that you stick with the name "activate" unless you have a strong backward compatibility reason to name it something else. You can always have your activate() method call some other legacy method.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above are correct. Now to have something like printing something on the shell you could write something like:

```
public interface PrintService {
    public void print();
}
```

Implentation:

```
public class PrintServiceImpl implements PrintService {

      @Override
      public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello from PrintServiceImpl!");
      }
}
```

component.xml:

```
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="service">
   <implementation class="service.PrintServiceImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="print.PrintService"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

And now you could use a Command to call your print method:

```
public class PrintCommand implements Command {

    private PrintService printer;

    public void setPrinter(PrintService printer) {
        this.printer = printer; 
    }

    public void unsetPrinter(PrintService printer) {
        this.printer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(String line, PrintStream arg1, PrintStream arg2) {    
        printer.print();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "print";
    }

    @Override
    public String getShortDescription() {
        return "just a printer";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage() {
        return "print";
    }

}
```

And your component.xml should have a new entry:

```
<component name="PrintCommand">
    <implementation class="PrintCommand"/>
    <service>
        <provide interface="org.apache.felix.shell.Command"/>
    </service>
    <reference
        name="printer"
        interface="PrintService"
        bind="setPrinter"
        unbind="unsetPrinter"
        cardinality="1..1"
        policy="static"
    />
</component>
```

The Command Interface is part of Apache Felix Shell and if you now run Felix and type `help` in your console you will see all registered commands and there is the PrintCommand as well `print`. If you now type print in the shell you will see the text.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this working? For me it was that the Eclipse .ds bundle just hadn't started yet, and as such the service wasn't registered (yet). When I started it manually my service was registered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are use annotations, XML file will be generated automatically under OSGI-INF/... folder.

```
  public interface PrintService {
    public void print();
  }

  implementation with annotations: 

  @Component(service = PrintService.class)
  public class PrintServiceImpl implements PrintService {

      @Activate
      public void activate() {
         print();
      }

      @Override
      public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello from PrintServiceImpl!");
      }
    }
```

As i said before, XML file created automatically. With @Component(service = PrintService.class) annotations, we register PrintService to OSGi framework(like registerService method in ServiceTracker). When service is registered, Activate method will be called. Method name can be anything. Just add @Activate annotations to say "when service is registered, call the method which is under @Activate annotations" to OSGi Framework.