# OSGi Declarative Service (ds) usage

Tags: java, eclipse, service, osgi, declarative

Right now I try to implement the services of my OSGi-application as ds.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to access consume the service.

My Service looks like this:

```
public interface IService {
    public void foo(<T> bar);
}
```

```
public class ServiceImpl implemets IService {
    public void foo( bar){
        ...
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="iservice">
   <implementation class="ServiceImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="IService"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

That's as far as I am right now.

But how can I access the service?

1. I tried the following solution: http://it-republik.de/jaxenter/artikel/OSGi-in-kleinen-Dosen-Services-auf-deklarative-Weise-2340.html

   But eclipse won't find the import for

   `ComponentContext` h**p://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/component/ComponentContext.html
2. I also found this solution:  h**p://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97690.rhtml

   But I'm a bit disappointed I'd have to wrap every single method and I'd have to use Eclipse specific apis

   There are the same problems with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034485/1737519 although the example uses the apache felix api and not the Eclipse api.

All I want to do is access/reference the service like this:

```
Iservice s = ???;
s.foo(<T> bar);
```

Thx for your help in advance!

P.S. sry for masking the links, but I can't include more than 2!

Comment: What is Eclipse-specific about the second solution? In particular the answer in the Stackoverflow link shows exactly how to do this and it doesn't require any Eclipse APIs. Also it doesn't require "wrapping every single method", can you explain what you meant by that?

Comment: Oh sry you are right, the second solution from stackoverflow doesn't use eclipse apis. But it uses the apache felix api org.apache.felix.shell.Command and the run method is actually wrapped within the execute method

Comment: it use the  org.apache.felix.shell.Command , is the service will provide osgi console command, in org.apache.felix.shell.impl.Activator.ShellServiceImpl will get all services which implement org.apache.felix.shell.Command interface.

Comment: Uhh, did you mistype? ServiceImpl must implement IService for this to work.

Comment: @user1737519 The linked example *only* uses a Felix Command to frame the example. It could have been anything; by implementing a command, Christian just showed an easy way to use the service. That's all. The execute method "wraps" the print method because it shows how to invoke the print method, which is exactly what you are asking for! So don't mistake the framing of the answer -- which really could have been anything -- for necessary dependencies. They are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to consume your service. I have invented a fictional Billing component that needs to call your `IService`. Instead of using the XML I am using bnd annotations, which are much more convenient:

```
@Component
public class Billing {

    private IService service;

    @Reference
    public void setService(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void billCustomer() {
         // Do some stuff related to billing, whatever.

         // Blah blah blah

         // Now call the service, even though it wasn't real Java because
         // the <T> type parameter was unbound, but who cares...
         service.foo(bar);

         // Yay.
    }
```

}

Comment: @user1737519, I have a complete example using the annotations that Neil mentions at https://github.com/bdelacretaz/OSGi-for-mere-mortals  - seeing those in action in a small example project might help.

Comment: That is totally correct. However I read that it is better to use xml-files: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/266860/766746/#msg_766746

Comment: @user1737519: That forum message is wrong. These are build-time annotations only, therefore there is zero runtime cost. Also the resulting class files can be run on Java 1.4, so long as you give the `-target` flag correctly to the Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

it use the  org.apache.felix.shell.Command , is the service will provide osgi console command, in org.apache.felix.shell.impl.Activator.ShellServiceImpl will get all services which implement org.apache.felix.shell.Command interface. so when user input a command name , the ShellServiceImpl will execute special service . 
Just let  services  customer know the interface , the interface is the contract between services provider and the services customer.

hope , it's usefull!

Comment: Could you please give me a code snippet? (Although I'm not allowed to use apache felix apis)